# Remove Parameter Hints Box in Visual Studio Code

Tags: popup, visual-studio-code, tooltip

Someone know's how to remove this box:
["help" box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/057h7.png)
It's better showed [here](https://github.com/fr1zle/vscode-elixir/issues/73)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Open the menu, chose the command `File > Preferences > Settings` to open or create a `settings.json` file where you can modify the behaviour of Visual Studio Code.

In this file, add the following line at an appropriate place:

```
"editor.parameterHints": false,
```

In newer version of Visual Studio Code you have to use this instead:

```
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
```

Reference:

- [Intellisense in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)
- [Visual Studio Code User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

Comment: This works, thank you so much, that thing is so annoying

Comment: More recently (October 2018 onwards) this is now:  ```"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,```

Comment: With vscode 1.69.2, I had to use the setting: `"editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off"`

Answer (score 2):

I went to File->Preferences->Settings and a tab opened with Commonly Used at the top.  Did Ctrl-F to search parameter, then uncheck the box which is saved automatically it will say.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

For me it didn't work but someone on github mention that once you start typing, if the parameter hints show up, just press `**ctrl + space**` and it won't show up again. It was simple and easy!

Answer (score 0):

To turn off parameter hints in VS Code through the GUI go to > preferences > settings, then type parameter in the search box. You will see Editor > Parameter Hints > Enabled. Just uncheck the box. That solved the problem for me. After searching for over an hour I stumbled on it myself. I only downloaded VS Code a few days ago so I have the newest version.

Comment: Pleae use bullet points and code block for better readability